# Is ModelMap empty?

Tags: java, spring

I Have a code:

```
public class testCustomer {

    private ModelMap customer;
    }
```

And getters/setters for above class.

And I have two methods:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=search")
    public void searchAction(
            ActionRequest request,
            ActionResponse response) {

            ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
            modelMap.put("rowsPerPage", 10);
            modelMap.put("page", 1);
            modelMap.put("total", 100);

            testCustomer.setCustomer(modelMap);
    }


@ResourceMapping(value="customer")
    public ModelAndView listCustomer(
            ResourceRequest req,
            ResourceResponse res) {


        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        MappingJacksonJsonView v = new MappingJacksonJsonView();

        mav.setView(v);
        if(testCustomer.getCustomer().isEmpty()){
            log.debug("List Customer Resource: " + "NULL");
            mav.addObject("data", null);
        } else {
            log.debug("List Customer Resource: " + testCustomer.getCustomer());         
            mav.addObject("dataListCustomer", testCustomer.getCustomer());
        }
        return mav;
    }
```

How Can I check in `@ResourceMapping` if testCustomer is empty or not? Because now I have `NullPointer Exeption` 
What is wrong in my code?

Comment: On what line are you getting the NPE?

Comment: On line if(testCustomer.getCustomer().isEmpty())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, `null` is different to "being empty". Calling any method on a `null` will result in a `NullPointerException`. You must explicitly test for `null` before calling `isEmpty()`.

Change your code to this:

```
if (testCustomer.getCustomer() == null || testCustomer.getCustomer().isEmpty())
```